# How to monitor and get alerts when a rollback occurs in MongoDB replica set?

Tags: mongodb, monitoring, rollback

I want to monitor the rollback directory and get an alert if new rollback files are created. How can I do that?

Comment: You could wirte script and create a cron job which runs at a specified interval of time and triggers a mail as soon as sees the rollback directory. Not sure MMS has this feature in-built.

Comment: Isn't there anything from MongoDB side that I could use like logs or some command which tells rollback has happened?

Comment: Yes, as soon as rollback happens there will be logs inside the rolled back mongod saying something like "Rolling back...". You could try and simulate a rollback scenario and see how logging happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a rollback happens, MongoDB records its data in a BSON files (in the "rollback" folder under your database "dbPath" directory), and most importantly the concerned replica set member gets its [state](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/replica-states/) flagged as ***ROLLBACK***. This "replica set member state" has a corresponding metrics named `state` ( `members.state` ), reported under the [replSetGetStatus](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/replSetGetStatus/#replSetGetStatus.members.state) command, that will be equal to **9** in case of rollback.

If you want to monitor this metric and receive an alert when a rollback occurs, you can:

- Write your own script that would trigger an alert every time one member of your replica set has its `state` statistic equal to **9** (you would collect this metric from the "replSetGetStatus" command), but it might be time-consuming
- Or use a monitoring tool that integrates with MongoDB, automatically collects metrics from your cluster(s), and gives you the ability to set up alerts on these statistics (here on `members.state`). For example, Datadog provides such alerting mechanisms on metrics [as explained here](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/monitor-mongodb-performance-with-datadog/#toc6).